# Power Query Merge With additional Table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have two table, Table 1 and Table 2 who have identical 3 columns. Table 2 has one additional column I’m trying to merge into one big table. The thing is, the three identical columns are not sorted, which is why I’m trying to use a power query.

I managed to merge the identical columns but now stuck with the additional column in Table 2 not merging/appending.

These queries are connected to external source and gets updated every day. Sorry I can’t share due to confidentiality:/

Edit1:
For example:

**Table 1**

```
AAA, 123, 1/1/2021
BBB, 499, 5/2/2021
```

**Table 2**

```
BBB, 499, 5/2/2021, Valid
AAA, 123, 1/1/2021, Invalid
```

The data is more complex and huge but the issue is with merging the two table while also including the extra column from Table 2.

Comment: To help us help you, please edit your question to provide a data sample (as TEXT, not an image), that demonstrates your problem. Also post your code (also as text). Finally, provide a sample (these could be images) of what your code run on this sanitized data produced, as well as what you would like

Comment: If it's confidential, please illustrate a few rows of anonymous data on the same format as your original data

Comment: Added example in original post

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's anything to merge. In your example, Table 2 contains everything.  Why not just use Table 2, perhaps sorted in the same order as Table 1.

Comment: Because both tables come from different sources with different formats. I should have mentioned this but what I posted are example formats after modifying the data to look alike.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are additional columns in Table 1. But from what you post, it seems like all of your information is in Table 2, and all you would need to do would be to sort Table 2 in whatever order you want, perhaps the same order as Table 1.

But you can join them easily enough in Power Query.

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    Typed1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,
        {{"ID", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    Typed2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,
        {{"ID", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date},{"Status", type text}}),
    Joined = Table.NestedJoin(Typed1,"ID",Typed2,"ID","Status"),
    ExpandStatus = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Joined, "Status", {"Status"}, {"Status"})
in
    ExpandStatus
```

[image]